# Как правильно сравнить два словаря?

Tags: python

У меня есть два словаря такого вида

```
old_dict = {'Anton':'454.44', 'Sergey':'345.65','Petr':'7634.88'}
new_dict = {'Anton':'1123.20', 'Sergey':'85.34','Petr':'677.09'}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно сравнить эти два словаря с условием, если в new_dict значение больше, чем в old_dict = вывести сообщение.
По ключам имеется ввиду, цифры сравнить, если больше, то вывести сообщение и так по каждому

**Заранее спасибо**!

Comment: Все значения или по ключам?

Comment: По ключам имеется ввиду, цифры сравнить, если больше, то вывести сообщение и так по каждому

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как то так

```
old_dict = {'Anton':'454.44', 'Sergey':'345.65','Petr':'7634.88'}
new_dict = {'Anton':'1123.20', 'Sergey':'85.34','Petr':'677.09'}


def main():
    for new, old in zip(new_dict.items(), old_dict.items()):
        if float(new[1]) > float(old[1]):
            print(f"{new[0]} заработал")
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
res = [(x, new_dict[x]) for x in new_dict.keys() if float(new_dict[x]) > float(old_dict[x])]
print(res)
```

> [('Anton', '1123.20')]